# to compare value in lob

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a condition like:

```sql
case when to_char(dbms_lob.substr(column1,10) = ' ' then null else column1
```

It is working fine, but I am restricted to not use the `dbms_lob` package. Is there any alternative?

Thanks

Comment: If you are restricted to only using the `DBMS_LOB` package and you have a solution that uses the `DBMS_LOB` package then I am failing to see the problem.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I can't use dbms_lob and any alternative to dbms_lob

Answer (score 1):

You appear be comparing the first 10 characters of a CLOB to a string literal containing a single space; that will only match if the CLOB contains a single space character. You can just use equals:

```sql
CASE WHEN TO_CHAR( column1 ) = ' ' THEN null ELSE column1 END
```

or you could use `LIKE` (but since you aren't using a wildcard this is just another equality comparison):

```sql
CASE WHEN column1 LIKE ' ' THEN null ELSE column1 END
```

or use `SUBSTR`:

```sql
CASE WHEN TO_CHAR( SUBSTR( column1, 1, 10 ) ) = ' ' THEN null ELSE column1 END
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d8286cca4d1e974bcaea4732db03ccdb)*